# Responsive UI depending on client platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

To support responsive UI on my game, i create this script

```cs
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformDependantUI : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] protected PlatformDependantUISettings computerSettings;
    [SerializeField] protected PlatformDependantUISettings mobileSettings;

    protected void Awake()
    {
        InitializeUI();
    }

    protected virtual void InitializeUI()
    {
#if UNITY_STANDALONE
        computerSettings.ApplySettings(this);
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
        mobileSettings.ApplySettings(this);
#elif UNITY_IOS
        mobileSettings.ApplySettings(this);
#endif
    }
}
```

And an object like this:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class PlatformDependantUISettings
{
    public GameObject[] deletedGameObjects;
    public bool disableSelfGameObject;
    public bool destroySelf;

    public Vector2 anchorMin;
    public Vector2 anchorMax;
    public Vector2 sizeDelta;
    public Vector2 position;

    public void ApplySettings(Component sender)
    {
        RectTransform transform = sender.GetComponent<RectTransform>();

        // Change the anchors
        transform.anchorMin = anchorMin;
        transform.anchorMax = anchorMax;

        // Change the position
        transform.anchoredPosition = position;
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

The problem is that for each of my UI elements, i have a the script on it, and twice a `PlatformDependantUISettings` object.
I used it for everything until now, but the problem comes with the inventory, i have dozens of item, each one containing 5 sub elements, if i place this script on each element, i think it will make the game toughly lag on game launch. Is there a way to optimize it or to reach my purpose another way ?

Is it a good idea to create two prefabs, one for the `PC Inventory item`, and one for the `Mobile Inventory Item`, and on Awake of the inventory item, if the platform is Android or iPhone, instantiate a `Mobile Inventory Item`, copy to it the stats, and then destroy the `PC Inventory Item` ?

Thank you !

Comment: can you clarify "Optimize"? Have you tried your proposed solution and found an issue with it?

Comment: Question: Why would the UI sizes and placement etc depend on platform rather than screen resolution, dimensions and aspect ratio?

Comment: On mobile the game is made to be played in landscape.
On PC the inventory is always shown, it's displayed on the size of the screen
On mobile there is a button to open the inventory in full screen, and then another one to clsoe it